# Any layout css for Angular 5 Material UI

Tags: material-ui, angular5

I was inspecting [Material UI for Angular 5](https://material.angular.io/) and didn't see any layout related css as part of the framework similar to [Material UI for angual v1.x](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment). Is there a way to achieve this or do I have to use some other css framework for layout & positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're referring to the [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).